# How to know if client side is authenticated (httpOnly cookie)

Tags: express, authentication, cookies, jwt, session-cookies

I have this login system between my React client and Express server. I'm using an httpOnly cookie containing a JWT token for authentication. When a user is logged in, I'd like to have the right side of my menubar show a Log out button instead of a Log in button.

But since my auth token is an httpOnly cookie, I can't check whether or not it is set to determine whether or not to show the logout or login button. What I did in my dev environment was send a companion cookie:

```js
// /login endpoint on my server side
res
.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', CLIENT_ORIGINS)
.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
.cookie('LoggedIn', 'true', { httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: 'none' })
.cookie('JWTAuthToken', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'none' })
```

and then check if `document.cookie` had `LoggedIn=true` to determine authentication state.

But with my app hosted on Azure App Service and on a public URL, I can't access my `LoggedIn` cookie with `document.cookie` anymore. I can see in devtools that the `LoggedIn` cookie has its domain set to my server URL, while the cookies being returned from `document.cookie` are set to `.(site name).org`. I've tried setting the domain of the `LoggedIn` cookie like so:

```js
.cookie('LoggedIn', 'true', { httpOnly: false, secure: true, sameSite: 'none', domain: '.(site name).org' })
```

but it seems that on client-side devtools their domains are still set to the server URL.

So are there any other ways to tell if I'm authenticated on the client side? Or does anyone know why my `LoggedIn` cookie domain isn't being set correctly? Thanks!